# Convert xml file to tree

Tags: xml, algorithm, stack

I saw this question on a forum and wanted to understand the problem. Is it expected to create a binary tree out of the xml or the xml tree itself to be printed (print xml).The question is listed below.We could use a stack like structure to print the xml but I just needed an example to understand this little better.

"Convert a xml file into a tree, assuming the file has been parsed and you have the iterator to get next node"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking to clarify some random assignment, which only the person who gave the assignment can do.

Comment: Although XML nodes don't have at most 2 children (i.e. it's an n-ary tree, not a binary tree), and nowhere in that sentence does it ask you to print it.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
The code is an exercise while going through the educative.io coderust
questions. The code is in GO & followed the suggestion in coderust to use 
a stack and xml tokenizer to decide the tree level of insertion.

The stack is a simple implementation using the local stack without using 
standard package in container/list, the xml decoder is from encoding/xml, 
the decoder already did tag matching so the code just handle the insertion 
of the tag using the xml.StartElement until it hits xml.CharData which is 
the inner xml string in the leaf node that needs to be inserted.

The code does not handle xml syntax errors like unmatched tags, for fully
functional parser, the xml.Unmarshal() should be used. This is an example
for a coding question on the spot implementation.

I added the testing xml strings and printTree() function to print the tree 
output for testing.  No plan to improve this code further.
*/

package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

const (
  xmlStr1 = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <users>
    <user type="admin">
      <name>Elliot</name>
      <social>
        <facebook>https://facebook.com</facebook>
        <twitter>https://twitter.com</twitter>
        <youtube>https://youtube.com</youtube>
      </social>
    </user>
    <user type="reader">
      <name>Fraser</name>
      <social>
        <facebook>https://facebook.com</facebook>
        <twitter>https://twitter.com</twitter>
        <youtube>https://youtube.com</youtube>
      </social>
    </user>
  </users>`

  xmlStr2 = `
  <html>
    <body>
      <div>
        <h1>CodeRust</h1>
        <a>http://coderust.com</a>
      </div>
      <div>
          <h2>Chapter 1</h2>
      </div>
      <div>
          <h3>Chapter 2</h3>
          <h4>Chapter 2.1</h4>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>`
)

type node struct {
  name string  // tag name from xml.StartElement.Name.Local
  tagOpen bool
  child []*node
}

// minimum error handling on xml syntax or missing tags
func xml2Tree(s string) (*node, error) {  // return nil if xml error
  stack := []*node{}  // empty stack using slice
  empty := func() bool { return len(stack) == 0 }
  push  := func(n *node) { stack = append(stack, n) }
  pop   := func() { stack = stack[0:len(stack) - 1] }
  peek  := func() *node  { return stack[len(stack)-1] }

  root := (*node)(nil)
  decoder := xml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(s))

  insertTag := func(n *node) {
    if root == nil {
      root = n
      push(n)
      return
    }
    peek().child = append(peek().child, n)
    push(n)
  }

  insertData := func(n *node) error {  // remove end tag to simplify the stack & state
    peek().child = append(peek().child, n)
    token, _ := decoder.Token()
    _, ok := token.(xml.EndElement)  // skip end tag
    if !ok { return fmt.Errorf("syntax error @ %s", n.name) }
    pop()  // remove tag, e.g., <h1> or <a> for this leaf
    return nil    // full element handled here,  no push & pop
  }

  for {
    token, _ := decoder.Token()    // no need to check EOF
    if token == nil { return root, nil }  // end of input string
    switch elem := token.(type) {
    case xml.StartElement:
      n := &node{ name: elem.Name.Local, tagOpen: true }
      insertTag(n)
    case xml.CharData:
      c := elem[0]
      if c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n' { break }  // filter stuff between tags
      n := &node{ name: string(elem) }  // nil []child by default
      if err := insertData(n); err != nil {
        return nil, err
      }
    case xml.EndElement:
      if empty() { return root, nil }
      if peek().tagOpen && strings.Contains(elem.Name.Local, peek().name) {  // match tag
        pop()
      } else {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unmatching tags %s %s", elem.Name, peek().name)
      }
    }
  }
  return root, nil
}

var level = 0
func printTree(r *node) {
  tab := func() {
    for i := 0; i < level; i++ {
      fmt.Printf("  ")
    }
  }
  level++
  tab()
  fmt.Printf("%s(%d)\n", r.name, level)
  for i := 0; i < len(r.child); i++ {
    printTree(r.child[i])
  }
  level--
}

func main() {
  root := (*node)(nil)
  root, _ = xml2Tree(xmlStr1)
  printTree(root)
  root, _ = xml2Tree(xmlStr2)
  printTree(root)
}
```

Comment: Please consider hitting the [edit] button under your post and adding an explanation to accompany your code. It will make your answer more useful to anyone who reads it, and make it more likely that you will receive upvotes.